# How to decide the best server image size to match in all android devices

Tags: android, image, server, size, screen

I'm developing an android app that supports tablets and mobile devices, my app uploads images to the server and displays it to the users with different screen sizes, the problem is that i don't know how to measure the best image dimensions that can appear without stretching in tablets, how can i measure the accepted image dimensions when user uploads the image?

Comment: Why would your server care about sending the image in a specific size? Send the full image to the device and resize the image on the device to the ImageView bounds like you should be doing. Either that or send the ImageView dimensions to your server and have your server resize the image to those dimensions and then send the image

Comment: @tyczj i need to know the most appropriate size to make sure that the image will appear in good quality in all screen sizes "phones or tablets", some times the user uploads long images that stretches in tablets and so on, if i resized the uploaded image in the app or the server i also need to know the dimension that will make me achieve the same result for example my image view in match parent width and 350 height, what is the best dimension here to resize my image to ?

Comment: Your question makes no sense because there is no such thing as "the most appropriate size". You can get the image view dimensions easily in your code. Better yet just use this library https://github.com/bumptech/glide and you dont have to worry about any of that

Comment: @tyczj i'm using Glide already and still when user upload images with different dimensions the images stretches according to the screen size, I'm trying to achieve a behavior like facebook and whatsapp when you try to upload an image they validate it against some dimensions already specified if it doesn't match the image doesn't get accepted, in my case i can't find that dimensions because i support different screen sizes and specially in android it differs from manufacturer and another, if i don't have a problem in image quality i wouldn't spend hours searching for solution